# Cassandra partition locations for different keyspaces/tables

Tags: cassandra

There was a related question about tables in the same keyspace having the same partition key, resulting in the data of those partitions to be on the same node.

What about if the keyspace is different and we have the same partitioning strategy: would two records (from different keyspaces) with the same partition key have their data on the same node?

Simplified example:

```
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE test_1 WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
cqlsh> CREATE KEYSPACE test_2 WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': '1'}  AND durable_writes = true;
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE test1.t (id int, val int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
cqlsh> CREATE TABLE test2.t (id int, val int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test1.t (id, val) VALUES (1,1);
cqlsh> INSERT INTO test2.t (id, val) VALUES (1,1);
```

Now would test1.t(1,1) be on the same data node as test2.t(1,1)?

I tried manually with a few records and checking with

```
nodetool getendpoints test1 t 1
nodetool getendpoints test2 t 1
```

seems to always return the same node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they will be the same. Token for both tables is murmur3(id) which would be the same ring position. If the replication strategy changes it would just change which replicas, but the 1st replica will be the same unless there is some DC restrictions.

Comment: so the keyspace doesn't play any role in calculating the hash? I guess I can find this by looking in the code but it will be nice to have this info here

Comment: `select token(id), id from test1.t` will print out all the tokens and the ids of existing partitions for that schema. The token wont change based on replication factor, but it might effect which replicas are chosen when using things like network topology where some DCs have zero replicas etc. but with SimpleStrategy its pretty straight forward (note: shouldn't ever really use SimpleStrategy in production)